# meaning of compound ratio

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Higher algebra by hall and knight states that"A compound ratio can be formed by multiplying together the fractions which denote them or by multiplying the antecedents to form new antecedent and multiplying the consequents to form new consequent" but what is the meaning of the word compound ratio.If ratio is used for comparison then what is the purpose of compound ratio?
 Can anyone help me?. I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example right below this definition clearly shows the ratio compounded is just multiplying the given ratios together. Antecedent multiplied by antecedent yields a new antecedent. Consequence multiplied by consequence yields a new consequence.

In short, ratios can be expressed in the form of fractions and therefore can be multiplied (Numerator to numerator and denominator to denominator) together to form a new fraction.

The book says nothing further about why we multiply these ratios together. Its usage, I guess, is to make the definitions of "duplicate\triplicate\sub-duplicate ratios" more precise.

On page 10, Examples._I-1 is the only place that the term "ratio compounded" can be found again.

Comment: Umm I think in next article it says about duplicate ,triplicate and sub duplicate ratio,but why ratio are compounded ?ratio is use for comparing two quantity then compound ratio is used for what?

Comment: @NamasivayamKalithasan The only reason I can think of is for making the definitions of those ratios more concise.